# Escaping backslash in namespaces with DQL (Doctrine 2)

Tags: namespaces, doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql, backslash

I'm a bit confused about writing queries in DQL.
From the official documentation:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyProject\Model\User u WHERE u.age > 20');
```

Why the backslash of the namespace is not escaped?
I'm getting a warning in Zend Studio for that reason, and it works anyway, but I think is just "luck", because neither \M nor \U are valid escaped sequences.

What do you think? is safe to use that syntax? or is better to escape the "\" always in DQL?

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyProject\\Model\\User u WHERE u.age > 20');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Dynamic namespace names (quoted identifiers) should escape backslash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.quote)

Looks like the first syntax is just lucky. :) I haven't tried it myself, so if you say that query with escaping works just as query without escping, it's better use escaped queries.

Comment: Btw, I've checked some working code in my project... Single backslash works even inside double-quoted strings. The only way to crash it is using single \ inside double-quoted string before some character, that forms an escape sequence together with \.

Comment: Yes, Doctrine's docs are really really wrong, I mean, their examples works fine, but only because they are using Uppercases for their names (hence you can't form an escape sequence) but the best practice is to escape the backslash, thanks for the link JOHN !

Answer (score 0):

Good point, but DQL takes query and matches to Namespace and Class before sending parsed query to database engine.

MyProject\Model\User is trim down to table name specified in User class.

> SELECT u FROM MyProject\Model\User u WHERE u.age > 20 becomes
>
> SELECT u FROM user[ie table name specified in User class] u WHERE
>   u.age > 20

Comment: yes I know that our DQL is not the final query, but "createQuery" receives a string, and a string is a string anywhere, and a backslash in a string is a special character. At really, I don't understand how can those DQL (strings) work without escaping the backslashes. What happen if we have a namespace like \new\Table? inside the string "\n" is not interpreted as a new line? If you escape the backslash in DQL you don't get any warning, and of course, the query works as expected. I think that is the "correct" way, but a I can't understand why no body is escaping the backslash in DQL.